# Battery not detected on Live Juno

Tags: usb, battery, release-juno

I would love to switch to elementaryOS Juno, so I tried a live version on USB.

Unfortunately, it seems like eOS doesn't detect my battery, so I don't have a battery icon and I don't have battery options too.

Tried the same Live USB on another laptop and battery is detected and works fine.

Any solutions? My pc is HP x2 10-p033nl

PS: I'm new to this world, so I still have to learn a lot

Comment: Okay, lets try something. Boot into the live USB > go with the "Try" > In terminal (with internet connection) type `sudo apt-get install acpi`and execute to install ACPI(Advanced Configuration and Power Interface) > execute `acpi` in the terminal. Let me know what you find.